# MySQL COUNT unexpected results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My database structure looks like this:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9ExyO6ktYcOenZ1WlBwdlY2R3c

Explanation for some of tables:

1. `answer_chk_results` - checked answers table. So if some answer doesn't exist on this table, it means it's unchecked
2. `lesson_questions` - lesson <-> question associations (by id) table

When I query database like this:

```
SELECT
    q.id,
    q.content,
    q.type
FROM
    `questions_and_exercises` q,
    `lesson_questions` lq
WHERE
    q.id = lq.qid
AND lq.lid = 1
```

I am getting all list of questions. But what I would like is a count of answers and checked answers for every question. When I use this query:

```
SELECT
    q.id,
    q.content,
    q.type,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.ID) answer_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT acr.id) checked_count
FROM
    `questions_and_exercises` q,
    `lesson_questions` lq
LEFT JOIN answers a ON a.qid = lq.qid,
LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON acr.aid = a.id
WHERE
    q.id = lq.qid
AND lq.lid = 1
```

The results is only 1 question with the wrong count of answers. (There are about 9-10 questions in my DB) What am I missing?

Comment: Doesn't count() already skip null records? The case statement seems superfluous

Comment: Why not use LEFT JOIN fot the lesson_questions table too?

Comment: @Jack tested without too. same result

Comment: @radashk I think it's pointless, because I'm getting questions list based on lesson id by `lesson_questions` table. So question id's from `lesson_questions`

Comment: You might be missing a group by

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `group by` would help, like:

```
select  q.id
,       q.content
,       q.type
,       count(distinct a.id) as answer_count
,       count(acr.checked) as checked_count
from    questions_and_exercises q
join    lesson_questions lq
on      q.id = lq.id
left join
        answers a 
on      a.qid = lq.qid
left join
        answer_chk_results acr 
on      acr.aid = a.id
group by
        q.id
,       q.content
,       q.type
```

Note that `count(acr.checked)` returns the number of answers with a row in the `answer_chk_results` table.  And `count(distinct acr.checked)` returns the number of different values of the checked column.  If checked is a boolean, that would always be one or zero.

Comment: Getting [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'a.id' in 'field list'

Comment: That's strange, both your example query and the Google doc say that `answers` as an `ID` column

Comment: But your question suggests `checked` should not be 0, because only checked answers have a row in the `answer_chk_results` table ?

Comment: My bad updated query to COUNT(DISTINCT acr.id) checked_count . But it doesn't fix main problem

Comment: The query in your question still lacks a `group by`, which means it can't work.  Perhaps you can set up a working example at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com), which would allow others to reproduce your problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16128/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-andomar)

Comment: Mate, I analyzed query: it has wrong. Query must at first check `lesson_questions` table by given lesson id, and get all `question ids` (qid) and only after that get questions from `question_and_exercises` table. So `JOIN lesson_questions lq ON q.id = lq.id` line is totally wrong.

Comment: For an inner join the order doesn't matter.  `a join b` is the same as `b join a`.  You can swap the order for readability, but the output should stay the same.

Comment: Another exciting problem caused by hidden columns in MySQL.